# Rails time zones

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm calling an external web service API that returns a timezone as listed in the Olson timezones database (e.g. "America/New_York"). However some of the values the API returned are "US/Pacific", "US/Eastern" and apparently don't match any of the Olson timezones in Rails 2.3.2. Can anyone shed some light on this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why they're being returned by the particular API you're using, but those entries do exist in the [PHP timezone implementation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php) (and maybe others), with the warning "Please do not use any of the timezones listed here (besides UTC), they only exist for backward compatible reasons."

I guess Rails uses a stricter implementation.